# Spring Web Flow on Tomcat 6.0.35 using Eclipse Indigo

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-webflow

I am new to Spring. I am trying to run a self-learning project called library, using Spring web flow on Tomcat. As the IDE I use Eclipse Indigo.

My project's WebContent folder structure is as following:

```
 WebContent
    pages
        welcome
            - introduction.jsp
            - menu.jsp
            - welcome.jsp
            - welcome.xml
    WEB-INF
        - library-service.xml
        - library-servlet.xml
        - library-webflow.xml
        - web.xml
        lib
            - commons-logging.jar
            - jstl.jar
            - ognl-2.6.9.jar
            - org.springframework.binding-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar
            - org.springframework.js-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar
            - org.springframework.webflow-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar
            - spring.jar
            - spring-webmvc.jar
            - standard.jar
```

As the content **web.xml**, it is as following:

```
<display-name>library</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/library-service.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>library</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>library</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/pages/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The content of **library-servlet.xml** is as following:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <import resource="library-webflow.xml" />   

</beans>
```

I have used the **library-service.xml** to declare to beans from service layers. Its content is as following:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean name="libraryService"
    class="com.library.service.LibraryService" />

</beans>
```

As the content of welcome.jsp page, it is as following:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Welcome!</h2>
    <a href="${flowExecutionUrl}&_eventId=next">Next</a>
    <a href="${flowExecutionUrl}&_eventId=skip">Skip</a>
</body>
</html>
```

As the content of **welcome.xml** is:

```
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">

    <view-state id="welcome">
        <transition on="next" to="introduction" />
        <transition on="skip" to="menu" />
</view-state>

    <view-state id="introduction">
        <transition on="next" to="menu" />
    </view-state>

    <view-state id="menu" />
</flow>
```

My problem is that when I runned welcome.jsp, I got the following nested error in Tomcat. I am using Tomcat 6.0.35.

```
Sep 19, 2012 4:41:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet library threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.webflow.conversation.impl.ContainedConversation.unlock(ContainedConversation.java:107)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.support.ConversationBackedFlowExecutionLock.unlock(ConversationBackedFlowExecutionLock.java:55)
    at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:178)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController.handleRequest(FlowController.java:174)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:236)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:257)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.ServletMvcView.doRender(ServletMvcView.java:50)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.AbstractMvcView.render(AbstractMvcView.java:180)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.render(ViewState.java:282)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.refresh(ViewState.java:241)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:219)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:259)
    at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController.handleRequest(FlowController.java:174)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Sep 19, 2012 4:41:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet library threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.webflow.conversation.impl.ContainedConversation.unlock(ContainedConversation.java:107)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.support.ConversationBackedFlowExecutionLock.unlock(ConversationBackedFlowExecutionLock.java:55)
    at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:178)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController.handleRequest(FlowController.java:174)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: :-) Yes. I would like to know where it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the webflow XML to the web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/library-service.xml, /WEB-INF/library-webflow.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Thanks duffymo, but it makes no difference.